# show top 5 used buffer at the bottom of buffer

Tags: buffers

I'm currently using helm-buffer,  and I have bind my c-x b to  (helm-buffers-list)，however when I switch buffer,  I still have to:
1.  c-x b
2.  type some works
3.  enter

sometimes, I probably just switch to prev/next buffer which can be done with switch-to={prev|next} buffer.  but I can't remember who is the prev/next buffer.

is there anyway to show top 5 used buffers at the bottom of buffer?

Comment: https://github.com/manateelazycat/awesome-tab is the thing I need.  supper easy to use.

Comment: If that's super easy to use, then Helm is ultra easy. With more tabs to switch between - Helm is unexceededly easy. With identically named files in different paths Helm is unparalleled.

Answer (score 1):

Better `helm-mini` instead of `helm-buffers-list`

`helm-mini` contains two pages: `helm-buffers-list` and `helm-recentf`(**Recentf** built-in package).
<kbd>C-o</kbd> to jump up/down between pages in buffer.

Comment: A word of support there. But I don't use recentf anymore and instead, rely on savehist. Thanks for the C-o comment. I didn't know about that.